# How to see oplog in standalone MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to see oplog so I have started MongoDB with as suggested in [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12039)

```
mongod --master --port 8888 --dbpath ...
```

But when I run

```
>db.oplog.rs.find()
```

It returns nothing

When I run

```
>db.oplog.rs.stats()
```

returns error

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "ns not found"
}
```

I have also tried these commands with '>use local'. I see same results.I am planning to read it using java oplog watcher API. But not able to get it. What am I missing.How to see oplog.

Comment: It would have been helpful to pass that link in the other question instead of just ignoring me, not replying, and then opening a new question. With that knowledge of a deprecated tech (I don't usually store active knowledge of deprecated techs) I was able to get to the bottom of it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it isn't replica set when you use `--master` it is actually the deprecated master-slave replication which got me thinking that maybe it is just a different name:

```
> show collections
oplog.$main
startup_log
> db.oplog.$main.find()
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104629, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104643, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104653, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104663, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104673, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104683, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1394104693, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : {  } }
```

Turns out I was right.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right !! Anyway I am using 'one member replica set' as you suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218175/selective-replication-in-mongodb .

Answer (score 12):

"oplog.rs" is found in the "local" database.  So, you can try something like:

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.find()
```

or from a different database:

```
db.getSiblingDB("local").oplog.rs.find()
```